# Why animation restarts on screen going off then on?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using a landscape-only app. There is an activity and animation. Animation is started in `onCreate` via `startAnimation()` method. So nothing unusual and nothing unordinary.

When animation ends, I turn screen off and then on, and **the animations restarts**!

Why is this happening and how to prevent this?

Since the app in in landscape only mode and Android screen off is in portrait, is this causing animation restart?

I haven't found such cases on the net.

Comment: How are you setting it landscape-only?

Comment: @KenWolf I found the solution by writing this question :). It was fixed by a simple Manifest's attribute. View my answer pls.

Comment: That's totally what I was gonna say :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning screen OFF and then ON indeed restarts the `Activity`.

So anyone facing the same problems, just add the usual attribute into the `Manifest` file next to the `Activity` where the animations occur.

Like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to check all this is to put Log in all `onCreate`, `onResume`, ... methods. Then, you should be able to see which methods are called during your tests.

Anyway, passing from Portrait to Landscape (or from Landscape to Portrait) and turning your screen off and on will probably restart the activity.